# Server validation does not trigger when submitting with Ajax Asp Mvc3 with kendo + knockout

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, fluentvalidation

I have Asp Mvc3 app. In my view I am using kendoui + knockoutjs. I am handling the client side validation with kendo validator. I am very new to asp mvc3 and I cannot make my server side validation work.

This is my business object:

```
[Validator(typeof(FranchiseInfoValidator))]
    public class FranchiseInfo
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using FluentValidation. This is the implementation of my validation rules:

```
public class FranchiseInfoValidator : AbstractValidator<FranchiseInfo>
    {
        public FranchiseInfoValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(franchiseInfo => franchiseInfo.FullName).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(franchiseInfo => franchiseInfo.ShortName).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

This is my view model:

```
public class FranchiseInfoViewModel
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my view strongly typed to FranchiseInfoViewModel:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.FranchiseInfoViewModel

<script src="../../Scripts/Details.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="franchiseForm" action="" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"> 
     <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="fullName">FullName:</label></td>
                <td><input id="fullName" data-bind= "value: FullName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="shortName">ShortName:</label></td>
                <td><input id="shortName" data-bind= "value: shortName" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="submit" class="k-button" data-bind="click: save" form="franchiseForm">Save Franchise</button>
</form>
```

On submit the form I am calling javascript function save:

```
$(function () {

    save = function () {

        // some logic

        $.ajax({
            url: "/franchise/SaveFranchise",
            type: "POST",
            data: { franchiseInfoViewModel: jsonData },               
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On save I am submitting the data in json format and sending the data to the SaveFranchise Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveFranchise(string franchiseInfoViewModel)
        {
            var franchiseInfoVM = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FranchiseInfoViewModel>(franchiseInfoViewModel);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                // do some action
            }

            return View();
        }
```

What I want to accomplish is on `(!ModelState.IsValid)` to return back to the view and show fluent validation error messages. For some reason, in my case ModelState.IsValid is always true.

As mentioned, I am very new to Asp Mvc 3. From the articles I have read, the examples are submitting the form to the server (without javascript) where there is binding and the server validation messages are returned to the view. But there the view is implemented with Razor and client side validation is done via jquery.

In my view I am using javascript view model with databindings ( kendoui + knockout). What should I do to do the server side validation in my case. Please help me. Thank You for your time and effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short answer:*

You should make use of model bindings in the controller action - doing so enables you to make use of `ModelState.IsValid`.

So your controller action:

```
public ActionResult SaveFranchise(string franchiseInfoViewModel)
```

.. should be changed into something like:

```
public ActionResult Create(FranchiseInfo franchiseInfo)
```

Be sure to post your form in a format that enables the model binder to instantiate an instance of the `FranchiseInfo` model. You can use JSON to do so, but I think it would be better (and simpler) if you just post the form using the standard `action` attribute on a form.

*Elaborated answer:*

One of the first things I would recommend, is that you use the model validation provided by the ASP.NET MVC framework including model bindings, model state, and data annotations for server side validation, as well as unobtrusive javascript for client side validation. Doing so would give you a way more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) implementation with clear [Separation of Concerns (SoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

To get there - I suggest you first start taking a look at model bindings in ASP.NET MVC.

As stated in ["The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx):

> With model binding, controller actions can be focused on providing business value and avoid wasting time with mundane request mapping and parsing.

To see this, this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) have a good definition of a model binder:

> A model binder in MVC provides a simple way to map posted form values to a .NET Framework type and pass the type to an action method as a parameter. (...) Model binders are like type converters, because they can convert HTTP requests into objects that are passed to an action method.

With that abstraction in hand, you will quickly see that the signature of:

```
public ActionResult SaveFranchise(string franchiseInfoViewModel)
```

.. could be changed into something like:

```
public ActionResult Create(FranchiseInfo franchiseInfo)
```

... and at this point, things are already starting to look more clean because code like your custom data mapping:

```
var franchiseInfoVM = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FranchiseInfoViewModel>(franchiseInfoViewModel);
```

... can be removed.

In general, you should not need to serialize the form into JSON and post that - instead you should take advantage of the model binding in MVC and submit the form data the standard way ( by using the `action` attribute on the form element - well, the model binder is able to bind objects based on JSON, but I think you get my point.. ). Actually, ASP.NET MVC makes it really simple to generate a form for a model using [`Html.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) - an example use of this is [shown here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view).

So, now when you have refactored the view to make use of a form that posts its data  without serializing the form data into JSON, you should take a look at the data annotations in MVC3.

As mentioned [in this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model), the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace of .NET...

> provides a built-in set of validation attributes that you can apply declaratively to any class or property. (...) The validation attributes specify behavior that you want to enforce on the model properties they are applied to.

One of the available annotations is the `Required` attribute - it defines that a particular model property must have a value. There are [several other attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) like `Range`, `MaxLength`, `RegularExpression`, etc. An example use of some of the attributes could look like this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre must be specified")]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Required")]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between $1 and $100")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

( The example is borrowed from: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model )

Populating your models with data annotations makes it very easy for you to check if the model is valid or not, at the point when a given form has been submitted, and your are about the check the validity of the provided model in a given action - it is here `ModelState.IsValid` proves to be useful.

As mentioned [in this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model):

> (...) The second Create method calls `ModelState.IsValid` to check whether the movie has any validation errors. Calling this method evaluates any validation attributes that have been applied to the object.

So at this point, you should be able to see that using data annotations to declare constraints/required behavior on your model will allow you to have a simple implementation where the logic is defined in the model and can easily be checked using `ModelState.IsValid`.

To expand a bit on this I can tell you a bit of my experience with model validation at server and client side in ASP.NET MVC3.

As you might already have guessed, my best experience with ASP.NET MVC3 when it comes to model validation is using data annotations and the built-in support for server-side validation through `ModelState.IsValid` and client-side validation through unobtrusive JavaScript.

For data annotations I use a combination of the built-in annotations, and the extensions provided by the [data annotation extension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) project.

There are a couple of good things about using ASP.NET MVC3's support for unobtrusive client validation.

- First of all, [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is really easy to achieve, as the model validation logic is only defined one place - and that is in the model where it belongs.
- Secondly you can get a more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) implementation in your view ( avoid duplicated logic and get code that is easier to maintain ) and let the framework do the heavy lifting for you instead.

An example of how to use unobtrusive client side validation in ASP.NET MVC3 can be found  [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

However, there are times when using the annotations might not seem that straigt forward - for instance when you want to validate properties such as credit cards and file extensions. In these cases where the need for logic calls for alternatives other than the basic annotations, I tend to use [data annotation extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) ( unless I can target my application for .NET 4.5 which, for instance, [has added a series of more attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like e.g. the `FileExtensionAttribute` ) as they provide a series of great annotation extensions that just works right out of the box ( there [exist a data annotation extensions nuget package for MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3) - so it is really simple to set up and start using ).

There are also special cases when you might have a property that depends on the state of your databse - e.g. if you want to check if a username already exists when a user is filling out a user registration form. In this scenario, the ASP.NET MVC3 remote validation annotation is your friend. As this [MSDN article states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx):

> ASP.NET MVC 3 provides a mechanism that can make a remote server call in order to validate a form field without posting the entire form to the server. This is useful when you have a field that cannot be validated on the client and is therefore likely to fail validation when the form is submitted.

And the nice thing about remote validation in ASP.NET MVC3 is, that it also is expressed using a data annotation ( as illustrated in [this blogpost](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2010/12/07/remote-validation-asp-net-mvc3.aspx) and in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx) ).

So to sum up - using these framework features (imo) really gives you a serious range of tools to cover more or less any kind of model validation "the right way" in ASP.NET MVC3.